# Can I make a function print into shell only if called with print?

Tags: python, python-3.x, return-value

So I have a function that returns a value. I'd like it to write it into shell only when called with print.
So `c.function()` doesn't return anything, while `print(c.function)` returns the value I need

Edit: I probably worded the question wrong

I have a class function that goes over an iterable, performs different tasks based on elements of the iterable. After completing the tasks it returns a number of the tasks completed. I need the function to write into shell only when called as `print(c.function(iterable))`, and to show nothing when called as `c.function(iterable)`, is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you know that if you just call `c.function()` then anything the function returns will simply be thrown away and not shown on screen?

Comment: @thatotherguy  That's not true in the REPL. You would have to do something like `_ = c.function()` to suppress the echo.

Comment: I'm using IDLE and it shows the return value with every call of the function, I want it to show when called with print and not show when called alone

Comment: IDLE's REPL doesn't reflect how things run in real programs. In a real program, return values are thrown away unless you use them explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you write a function like,

```
def foo():
    a = "This works."
    return a
```

then call the function in the script like
`foo()`
nothing gets printed.

However, if you assign the function return call to a variable like
`b = foo()`
and `print(b)`, then you get the result printed.

Comment: Now I realise, that I forgot to mention, that the function has an input value, so when I call it a few times, it gives different return values and thus i can't assign it to just a single variable like that

Comment: When you call the function with different inputs, assign the results to different variables and print the outputs as required. Please update your question with the correct code/details for others to be able to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign to a dummy variable when you want to hide the output:

```
>>> _ = c.function()
```

And call the function normally when you want to view the output:

```
>>> c.function()
'the value you need'
```

Just in case you need to view the result, you can:

```
>>> _
'the value you need'
```

Although `_` is also used in some Python shells as a special variable for the last value evaluated, so this might not always work. You might be able to rig up a fancy solution by assigning to a simple name that points to a property that appends to a list, but that seems like a lot of effort.

FWIW IPython can be made to not echo the value with a semicolon (e.g. `1;` doesn't print anything) or [can be set to not automatically echo values](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html#configtrait-InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity) plus [it automatically records every input and output](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/tutorial.html#history).